# gdal_grid unable to get nodata outside of original data area

Tags: gdal, csv

I have a vector based csv file that I want to convert into a grid using gdal_grid, but I want to force null data values strictly around the area where there is data.  I can get gdal_grid to work but it is always just smoothing the whole grid rather than giving me null data outside of the shape. Can someone tell me what settings to use to make sure that I get null data inside the grid where there is no data within the original csv.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok well I gave up trying to get it to work this way and instead did the following:

1. Create a convex Hull using DotSpatial around the vector verts
2. Converted the convex hull to a concave hull by finding the nearest point in the data to the convex hull line and adding verts to the polygon tied to the nearest point and saved the polygon out to a shapefile
3. Converted vector to grid using gdal_grid
4. Masked the grid by using `gdalwarp` with syntax:

   `-of GTIFF -dstnodata 0 -cutline -shpfile infile outfile`
5. Converted to XYZ using `Gdal_Translate`
6. Read in all the verts from xyz where not equal to 0

This gave me a gridded version of the original vector plot without any additional data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the interpolation algorithm's nodata, radius1, radius2, and min_points settings, and with old versions of gdal_grid, you will need an additional step to identify the nodata value filled pixels as nodata:

Expanding an example from http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html :

```
gdal_grid -a invdist:power=2.0:smoothing=1.0:nodata=-9999:radius1=1:radius2=1:min_points=1 \
          -txe 85000 89000 -tye 894000 890000 \
          -outsize 400 400 -of GTiff -ot Float64 -l dem dem.vrt temp.tiff
gdal_translate -a_nodata -9999 temp.tiff dem.tiff
```

Versions of gdal_grid newer than than 2014-05-08 (per http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/27565) should not require the gdal_translate workaround.